# How to use my c style func obtained by dlsym in my c++ program

Tags: c++, c, dlopen, dlsym

SO basically i dont know hu use this funciton "createLib" i can't seem to be able to use it:

```
auto createLibFunc = dlsym(lib, symbol.c_str());
```

This works, i opened my dymacally loaded lib with dlopen, i can get functions symbols with dlsym but i dont know how to uanch ceateLibFunc(); after i fetched it, it should be something like createLibFunc(); as easy no? here's the createLibs func:

```
extern "C" IDisplayModule *createLib()
{
    return new LibNcurses();
}
```

Comment: What type do you think `auto` is going to deduce for the return value from `dlsym()`?  I think this is somewhere that you can't sensibly use `auto`.  You'll need a `reinterpret_cast<IDisplayModule *(*)()>`, I think — unless it's a `static_cast`.  And the type of `createLibFunc` needs to be `IDisplayModule *(*createLibFunc)()`.  I don't think the `extern "C"` linkage affects the pointer type, but I'm willing to learn otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: "Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical." §9.11/p1. Also see the `extern "C" typedef` example in p4. (`typedef` will be very useful in this case.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If the type contains a function type, then the signature of the function will be mangled by C++.

Answer (score 1):

The most readable solution IMHO is to create a type alias:

```
extern "C" typedef IDisplayModule* CreateLibT();
```

Then you can use it to declare the type of your function pointer:

```
auto createLibFunc = reinterpret_cast<CreateLibT*>(dlsym(lib, symbol.c_str()));
```